# Данные из таблицы в массив php?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть таблица значения левой колонки которой формируются их php, все остальные значения пользователь заполняет самостоятельно. Как мне средствами php собрать все данные из таблицы и засунуть их массив для дальнейшего сравнения и записи в БД?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы пытались?

Comment: Если честно, не совсем понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как обычную форму.
Табличку выводите? Вероятно у каждой строчки есть свой уникальный id, и для каждого селекта в инпуте соответствующее имя назначить

```html
<input type="text" name="status[id]" value="">
```

И после отправки будет многомерный массив $_POST

что-то типо такого

```
Array
(
    [status] => Array
        (
            [4] => 11
            [5] => 33
        )

    [somethin] => Array
        (
            [4] => 22
            [5] => 44
        )

)
```